# How to run a copy of a Discord bot through a proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, discord.js, pm2

I have a Discord bot written in `discord.js`. I created a referral system so that everyone can create a copy of my Discord bot with their own token, but there was a small problem. I don't know how to run a copy of my Discord bot through a **proxy** so that there are several identical bots from one VPS, but with different **tokens** and with different **proxies**.

I thought about choosing the option to run a copy through `child_process` or through `pm2`, but I did not find an option how to use a proxy in these cases. Can you please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution!** This is how proxies can be used:
https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3039#issuecomment-1033955220

Comment: Please add in the answer to this question and provide the source link as a reference